# How can I make xampp live on the internet?

Tags: xampp

I am running xampp on my PC for a dev server but I would like to make it go on the internet, so I can show certain people work I am doing.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: If you do expose your dev server to the internet, be sure to use the latest version of xampp (so that the components are up to date with minimal security vulnerabilities) and monitor the system (or bring it up for demonstration, then take it back down immediately).  It won't take long for the system to be scanned by potential attackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read the instructions for your router and then setup port forwarding to the machine that hosts the app, normally port 80 tcp

Then give your friends the external ip address of the router, you can normally get this from the routers config or by visiting a site such as [whatsmyip.org](http://whatismyip.org/).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make some port available to the outside world from your computer.  If your ISP allows port 80, which most http traffic moves over, then go into the settings of your router.  You need to forward this port to the IP of your machine.

internets ->  | (router) | -> Computer

1) Incoming request on port 80 from your modems IP address

2) Router forwards this request to port 80 on your computer

Once this is done, you need to either find the address of your modem and use that, or using a service with [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) which is included in many routers.