# How to use my IP with Portforwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make xampp live on the internet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/45479/how-can-i-make-xampp-live-on-the-internet)

I am trying to access my dev server from the internet (personal use only) using something like www.no-ip.com

I have set up a host on no-ip.com and have set my router to forward port 80.  SO when I access 192.168.1. 100 it goes to my webserver however when I access my IP that is shown to the world, it goes to some kind of admin area from my DSL host it says "zyxel" instead of going to my server, any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: Configure your router to forward the port. If you did, review your settings. If you did the review, contact the router's support.

Comment: @mailq trying to accomplish the same thing, but this time I have it all set up, it seems my ISP is somehow forwarding on it's own though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router can't both provide its administrative interface on port 80 and forward port 80. If you've already configured it to forward port 80, you just need to move the administrative interface to another port, typically 8000 or 8080.

Some routers simply cannot forward port 80 (because their administrative interface is permanently locked to that port). In that case, you'll need to put your server on another port, such as 8000 or 8080.

**Update**: If your router isn't made by Zyxel, then you have inadvertently configured double-NAT. Your ISP provided a NAT router. If that Zyxel pages isn't the configuration for your router, then you need to do one of two things:

1. Decide to use only your router and reconfigure your ISP's router to act as a bridge.
2. Decide to use your ISP's router and reconfigure your router to act as a bridge.

Comment: Or change your router to one that does allow you to change the remote administration port.